# Is it possible to load url before showing its content?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-chrome, browser

What i'm trying to accomplish :
after click on preview div, i want to expand it to screen size, showing some loader of my own, and when the new url is ready - show its content.

is it even possible ?

```
const Works = ({changed}) => {
    const [works, setWorks] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        const myWorks = workService.getWorks()
        setWorks(myWorks)
    }, [])

    const openLink = async link => {
        // await load the url and show some content
        // show url content
    }

    return (
        <Page className={styles.works} changed={changed}>
            {
                works.map(({id, title, link, imgUrl}, i) => {
                    return (
                        <div 
                        key={id}
                        className={styles.work}
                        style={style}
                        onClick={() => handleClick(i)}>
                            <button onClick={() => openLink(link)}>Open App</button>
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }
        </Page>
    )
}
```

Comment: You can optionally hide the content till it's all set. Perhaps with some loading animation.

Answer (score 0):

you can hide the content you want till it's completely loaded and ready then display it.